# How to use embeded firebird database in electron.net using .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, electron, firebird-embedded, electron.net

I have an electron.net project with .net core and I want to use the Firebird embedded database engine. How can i achieve this?

Simply, I want to add the Firebird embedded DLL into my electron.net project. so it help me to use Firebird related functionality.

Comment: I'm stuck in the same problem.

Comment: @HirenPatel Yes, I just want to add firebird embedded dll to connect firebird database using electron.net project.

Comment: Consider asking your question on the firebird net-provider Google Group.